# "will have to" in a past tense clause

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood

> We decided that we would have to stay at home.
>
> We decided that we will have to stay at home.

Which one of the above is right? My grammar knowledge told me the first one, but how do we distinguish the "would" here from a "would" in `Subjunctive Mood`?

Comment: In my opinion both are "right", but they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: What makes you think that "would" is the subjunctive mood; it isn't. The subjunctive is a clause type that is headed by a plain form verb, as in "It is vital that I **be** kept informed". The difference between your two examples is that "would" conveys a greater degree of modal remoteness than "will". It may even be a conditional, where the condition is inferrable from the context: "We decided that if it rains we would have to stay at home".

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the two meanings of the word *would*. It is both the past tense of will and the subjunctive. Here it is the past tense of will. The two sentences mean different things:

> We decided that we would stay at home.

In this case you made a decision in the past that you would stay home in the past. It says nothing about what you are doing now.

> We decided that we will have to stay home.

In this case you made a decision in he past that you will have to stay home in the present.

So, in the first case you could say "we decided we would stay home, which we did, but now we are going out." You are going out now because you only stayed home in the past.

In the second case "We decided we will stay home, but now we are going out", here you did NOT stay home, evidently you changed you mind and went out anyway.

My advice, given what is going on in the world today? "Stay home"!!!!

Comment: In the sentence "We decided that we will have to stay home", the decision part is 'past', and what was decided is yet to happen. If 'stay home' is also a dismissed decision, it should be "We decided (that) we would have to stay at home." Here, one is unsure whether 'they stayed home or didn't"